# iAd does not rotate

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, orientation, iad

I have a Universal app with 1 iAd. Now I need to support both orientations..

I use the following code;

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if ( &ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait != NULL) {
        // NEWER
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
            adView_.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
        else
            adView_.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    } else {
        // OLDER
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
            adView_.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32;
        else
            adView_.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
    }
}
```

But as soon as I rotate to portrait, my app crashes with following error;

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'currentContentSize must
>   be one of the requiredContentSizes; 'ADBannerContentSizeLandscape' is
>   not in {(
>       ADBannerContentSizePortrait )}'

I am testing on IOS4.3 simulator.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Please suggest for the above question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"4.2" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending) {

    adBanner.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];

    adBanner.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;

    NSLog(@"below 4.2");

} else {

    adBanner.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];

    adBanner.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;

    NSLog(@"4.2 or above");

}
```